# Calling API from JavaScript Frontend: 401 unauthorized using angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, angularfire

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/authenticating-users) tutorial on adding firebase authentication to my webapp using endpoints v2 (migrated from v1 yesterday).

I previously had google accounts authentication only but want to switch to firebase for adding e.g. facebook.

When I call my API from my JavaScript Frontend (built with angularJS & angularfire) I get a 401 unauthorized.

I feel, I am missing a logical step:

1. I can log-in on the client-side (pop-up opens and my facebook-name is displayed).
2. Missing step?
3. endpoints.get_current_user() does not get a user.

Where am I going wrong?

This is what I want to initialize the page where I want to get a profile from the backend:

```
`/**
         * Initialize profile page.
         * Update the profile if the user's profile has been stored.
         */
        $scope.init = function () {
            var retrieveProfileCallback = function () {
                $scope.profile = {};
                $scope.loading = true;
                gapi.client.myapi.getProfile().execute(function (resp) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.loading = false;
                            if (resp.error) {
                                // Failed to get a user profile.
                            } else {
                                // Succeeded to get the user profile.
                                $scope.profile.displayName = resp.result.displayName;
                                $scope.profile.someOtherProperty = resp.result.someOtherProperty;
                                $scope.initialProfile = resp.result;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                );
            };
            if (!firebaseUser) {
                //TODO
            } else {
                retrieveProfileCallback();
            }
        };`
```

This is the start of the method that is ultimatively called from getProfile()-endpoint:

```
def _getProfileFromUser(self):
    """Return user Profile from datastore, creating new one if non-existent."""
    ## Make sure user is authed
    user = endpoints.get_current_user()
    if not user:
        raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('Authorization required')
```

Here is my API decorator (openapi.json has been deployed):

```
# - - - - firebase - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

firebase_issuer = endpoints.Issuer(
    issuer='https://securetoken.google.com/appname-123456',
    jwks_uri='https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com')

# - - - - Endpoints API  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

@endpoints.api(name='myapi',
               version='v1',

               scopes=[EMAIL_SCOPE],
               issuers={'firebase': firebase_issuer})
class MyApi(remote.Service):
```

I feel like I am massively misinterpreting the tutorials. It seems too easy and does not work. 
E.g. for the google accounts authorization I initialized the oauth2 api like so in the index.html:

```
`<script>
        function init() {
            gapi.client.load('myapi', 'v1', null, '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['conferenceApp']);
            });
        };
    </script>`
```

I took that out because I figured I am switiching to firebase.
Like so:

```
`<script>
        /**
         * Initializes the Google API JavaScript client. Bootstrap the angular module after loading the Google libraries
         * so that Google JavaScript library ready in the angular modules.
         */
        function init() {
            gapi.client.load('myapi', 'v1', null, '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api', function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });
        };
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The openapi configuration looks fine. The problem is with the client code, which handles sign-in flow to get a Firebase auth token. You need to use Firebase web SDK instead of Google JS SDK. You can take a look at the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin.